# C++ making a class function member of another class function

Tags: c++, class, function, member

I sincerely hope that people on here don't mind these sorts of questions.
After having searched plenty of times, perhaps with the wrong search terms - nevertheless - I do not seem to be able to find ANYTHING on this.
Yes, I have looked through cplusplus' documentation, yet I still could not find out the answer.

My question is simple, how do I make it so that a function can only be called via another function?

Here's an example

```
class someclas{
public:
void screen():
void setsomevariable (int somevariable){}
}clas;
```

And when I call the function, setsomevariable(), it should only be able to be used after having called the screen function. As such:

```
clas.screen().setsomevariable(..);
```

Again, how do I make this function a member of screen() alone?

Comment: *why* do you want to do this?

Comment: Well, I need to only alter the value of the preceding function (screen)...
This is JUST an example..

Comment: Hard to tell what is being asked here. It is easy to make one function return a class for which another function is a member, but it is not clear if that would answer the question.

Comment: that's why I asked the "why" question. It's better to know what you're really trying to do...

Comment: upvote. I would overload screen().

Comment: I am wanting to create a function which can only be called by another function. Never mind the purpose. I am simply looking for an answer on how to declare this function..

Comment: Thanks for the -1, Karoly.
It wouldn't make a difference whether I wanted it for its mere looks, or for something actually practical. Considering my already given example, though sufficient enough, you should be able to get at least a general idea.
Oh, and thank you, Fred, for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does match your requirements, but doesn't necessarily meet your needs. Would like to help more but you're stubbornly refusing to give details...

```
class Screen {
    public:
    void setsomevariable (int somevariable) {}
};

class someclas {
    Screen s;
    public:
    Screen& screen() { return s; }
} clas;
```

Comment: I guess I'll have to give up the idea.
Thank you for your post, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A member function belongs to a class. You can't make a function a member of another.

You could keep a boolean in your class, and throw an exception if screen wasnt called before. But it's an ugly solution..

```
class someclas{
public:
  someclas & screen() { // returns a reference to your class to enable the clas.screen().setsomevariable() syntax
    screenCalled = true;
    return *this;
  }
  void setsomevariable (int somevariable){
    if (!screenCalled) {
      throw std::exception();
    }
    // some code
    screenCalled = false;
  }
  bool screenCalled;
}clas;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the example.
A question, though. QT has it so you can only call <whatever function it may be> if you call it after calling a specific function of an class. I.e.,, you can only call do() if you call item first.
Can anyone explain why this is so - or rather how this is so?

Comment: @user1707244 Karoly's answer is *how* it is so. The function returns a reference to a type that has the member function you want.